# What is the "official" way to configure Mouse wheel resolution on Gnome (instead Solaar)

Tags: gnome, mouse, display-resolution, logitech

I use Gnome on Ubuntu 20.10 and a [Logistech MX Master 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Logitech_products#Pointing_devices) mouse connected on [Logitech Unifying Receiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logitech_Unifying_receiver).

For the moment, I use [Solaar](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar) manager to configure the mouse wheel resolution configuration (sorry the screenshot is in French):

[image]

When « Mouse wheel resolution » is enable, page scrolling is "smooth" in all applactions (Gtk, Firefox...).

I didn't find this option in [Gnome Tweaks](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks) application.

Issue: often, I need to disable/enable « Mouse wheel resolution » (« Résolution de la molette ») toggle to reactivate this feature.

Question: what is the "official" way to configure this option in Gnome?

Best regards,
Stéphane

---

Same request on:

- GitHub [`pwr-Solaar/Solaar`](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/issues/1124)
- GitLab Gnome Tweaks issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/-/issues/345